# How to port Javascript library to React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ar.js

Could anyone give some general guidance or point to an example of how to port a JavaScript library into a React Native component?

Specifically, I am interested in building a React Native component wrapper for [AR.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/README.md), but I have no idea how to go about converting their system (which uses HTML`<a-scene>` elements) into something I could use as React Native markup.

Comment: Not very familiar with react native, I just use plain react... but the process for making components should be pretty much the same I imagine. If your 'scenes' are going to be pretty similar with only a few properties changing and such, it;d be pretty easy to make your component, but otherwise I'd recommend just going with a prebuilt binding for AR.js, like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-arkit)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot port AR.js into React-native without writing a binding
Learn more here [Bridging in React-native](https://tadeuzagallo.com/blog/react-native-bridge/)

But still there is a dummy option: use [`WebView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) and feed with html files (*test it by opening AR.js demo on Safari of iOS first*)

Comment: I don't think we need a tl;dr for your answer

Comment: @Eden agree sir